# glob.glob from multiple paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I have the following code

```
os.chdir("X:\data1")
for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
```

to find all the `.pdf` files in `X:\data1\` directory

I would like to also find all the `.txt` file in `Y:\data2\` directory

I have this snippet in multiple places in the source code, so I would like to make only a little change.

Comment: Do you want to replace `os.chdir(dir); glob.glob("*.pdf")` with something that yields both `pdf` and `txt` in a single loop?

Comment: @norok2 Yes, but from diferent directories. The files maybe in various cases e.g. PDF, PdF etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this do?

```
import os
import glob


def ignore_case(pattern):
    return ''.join((f'[{c.lower()}{c.upper()}]' if c.isalpha() else c for c in pattern))


def multi_glob(patterns):
    for path, pattern in patterns:
        yield from glob.iglob(os.path.join(path, ignore_case(pattern)))


list(multi_glob((("X:\data1", "*.pdf"), ("Y:\data2", "*.txt"))))
```

---

Essentially, instead of `os.chdir(path); glob.glob(pattern)` you could just do `glob.glob(os.path.join(path, pattern))`.
If you you want this to happen for multiple path/pattern combinations, you could just have a loop through them.
Finally, to get case insensitive patterns, just replace each letter `c` of the pattern with `[cC]`.

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite old, but since I personally prefer `pathlib` to `os` I'd like to share my answer using `pathlib`:

The main part of the answer is certainly to outsource the whole code to a function. And then it could look like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List

def find_files(directory: str, extension: str) -> List[Path]:
    path = Path(directory)
    return list(path.glob(f"*{extension}"))

files_pdf = find_files("X:/data1/", ".pdf")
files_txt = find_files("Y:/data2/", ".txt")
```

`pathlib`'s glob returns all found files according to the given pattern, which can be returned e.g. as a list.